# Shared memory declaration inside device

Tags: c, image, cuda, histogram, gpu-shared-memory

How many shared memory decalrations are allowed inside the device kernel in CUDA?

Can we do something like this:

```
extern __shared__ float a[];
extern __shared__ float b[];
```

I wish to have 2 arrays of different sizes. For instance in a 1024x768 image. I can do parallel minimization by first minimizing across rows and then across columns. So to store intermediate values i will require

```
sizeof(a)/sizeof(float) == 768
```

and

```
sizeof(b)/sizeof(float) == 1024
```

Or should I just initialize one long 1D shared array and append `a` and `b`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have as many shared memory declarations as you like. However, the runtime only allocates a single shared memory buffer, and each shared memory array will be allocated the same address (i.e. the starting address of the shared memory allocation). So, for example, this:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern __shared__ int a[];
extern __shared__ int b[];
extern __shared__ int c[];

__global__
void kernel(void)
{
    int * a0 = &a[0];
    int * b0 = &b[0];
    int * c0 = &c[0];

    printf("a0 = %#x \n", a0);
    printf("b0 = %#x \n", b0);
    printf("c0 = %#x \n", c0);
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1,1,1024>>>();
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

does this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_30 -run extshm.cu 
a0 = 0x1000000 
b0 = 0x1000000 
c0 = 0x1000000
```

If you wanted to have two shared arrays, then on any supported (ie. compute capability >= 2.0) GPU, you can do something like this:

```
#include <cstdio>

extern __shared__ int a[];

__global__
void kernel(void)
{
    int * a0 = &a[0];
    int * b0 = &a[1024];
    int * c0 = &a[1024+768];

    printf("a0 = %#x \n", a0);
    printf("b0 = %#x \n", b0);
    printf("c0 = %#x \n", c0);
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<1,1,1024+768+512>>>();
    cudaDeviceReset();

    return 0;
}
```

which gives:

```
nvcc -arch=sm_30 -run extshm2.cu 
a0 = 0x1000000 
b0 = 0x1001000 
c0 = 0x1001c00
```

The latter is what you are looking for, I think.

Comment: An example is given in [the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) as well.